# Is Method local variable will garbage collected if stored in static storage?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, connection

I am creating a client class, which will connect to different type of database. Following is the code snippet what I am trying to do.

```
public class Client{
    private static Map<ApplicationTypeEnum, Connection> connectionPool = new HashMap<>();

    public void init() throws Exception {

        try {
           Connection con1 = getConnection(someparams...);
           connectionPool.put("app-1",con1)
           Connection con2 = getConnection(someparams...);
           connectionPool.put("app-2",con2)
        } catch (Exception pe) {
            throw pe;
        }
    }
}
```

Now the `Connection` object are local to `init`, so is there any chance that the `Connection`objects will be garbage collected when control is out of `init` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as any references exist pointing to these objects, they won't be garbage collected. In your case you have static variable `connectionPool` pointing to map, holding these objects. If you remove these objects from the above mentioned map or assign another map to `connectionPool` without these objects and will not have any other references to these objects, than yes, they will be collected.

Answer (score 2):

> Is Method local variable will garbage collected if stored in static
>   storage?

A variable is never garbage collected.
Only objects are garbage collected.
An object is illegible to be collected when it is not referenced by another other living object.
 The object may be referenced by a static or an instance field. It doesn't matter for the GC.
But as a side note, `static` fields are not eligible to the GC.

In your actual code, the `Connection`s you create in the `init()` method are referenced by the `connectionPool static map`.
So as the `Connection`s are referenced by at least one living object, these are not eligible to be collected.

Answer (score 1):

No. Because you have stored the references in the `static` `connectionPool` they are still reachable, and are not eligible for garbage collection.